# Trigger a SQL Server job from another job

Tags: sql-server-2012, jobs

There is job which first generates the data in initial steps and in later steps it then copies the data to 4 different servers. Since I wanted the parallel execution I created another job which handles copying the data to 2 servers and originally existing job copies data to 2 servers. I want some mechanism to trigger the new job after the initial steps of generation of data of exiting job runs successfully. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I know almost nothing about sql-server, but maybe this will help? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31104/calling-a-sql-server-job-within-another-job

Comment: You could create custom solution, but how about SSIS package fired by SQL Server agent that will do copying in parallel

Comment: @Lee i want copying the data in parallel

Comment: @lad2025 can you please explain a bit more? each step of copying is actually an ssis package already.

Comment: @TanuJain So create parent package that will execute child packages in parallel like [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3138/parallel-execution-of-child-sql-server-integration-services-packages-using-for-loop-containers/)

Answer (score 4):

You can add the below command wherever you want to start the other job execution:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'other_job_name'
```

Comment: If i would add this as some step in my job then will run sequentially. i want second job and first job to run in parallel

Comment: Explanation : Job1 first 2 steps generated data and next 2 steps copies data. job2 copies data to another 2 servers. i want job2 to run after data is genearted by job1. now if i will add new step in job 1 after first 2 steps of data generation then job 2 will start running and job1 data copying will only start after job2 has finished running. i want copying to be in parallel

Comment: No Tanu. If you add this command it will start the other job and as soon as it starts the code will move on on job 1. This command won't wait the job to finish to move on.

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: I have just tried. in my case in job history it is displaying the step which contains EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'other_job_name'  to be executed successfuly but next step hasn't started yet. it's waiting for this step to complete.

Comment: In my test I add the sp_start_job inside a stored procedure. The proc continues executing after the job starts, if that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'job_name';
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.